# Instr - Last index of last character

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm using an Oracle 11g DB and I want to find the position of the last character of a string.

For example:

```
"City=Amsterdam"
```

The string in this case would be "City=", I would like to get the position of the "=".
I know INSTR(Input,'City=', 1, 1)+4, would kinda work but I am looking for another way.

edit: Basically I want to use a substr function to extract "Amsterdam". But the select statement should be as clean as possible.

What I forgot to mention, the string contains more than "City=Amsterdam", it contains also "Customer=124"

```
"City=Amsterdam"; "Customer=124"
```

Comment: It would be easier if you could explain what you expect to receive. Please provide som demo data, and expected output. Do you want to know the last index of '=' or?

Comment: Do you want to receive 5 (which is the index of =) or do you want to receive 14 (the index of last m in amsterdam) or do you want to receive 9 (which is index of last m in amsterdam from start pos after = equal sign) ???

Comment: Basically I want to use a substr function to extract "Amsterdam". But the select statement should be as clean as possible.

Comment: updated answer, if fields exist before or after city= ... see below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSTR('City=Amsterdam', '=', -1)
```

use -1 for start pos!

from your comment, answer 2

```
select SUBSTR( input, INSTR(input, '=', -1)+1 ) as city 
  from yourTable;
```

And if you have more fields, before or after, as you mentions with customer=... you can do:

```
select substr(input, 
              INSTR(input,'City=')+5, 
              INSTR(input,'"', INSTR(input,'City='))-INSTR(input,'City=')-5 
             ) as city from city;
```

And some kind of "fancy" query, to comment and make it more flexible with other fields...

```
select substr(c.input, c.citystart, c.cityend - c.citystart) as city
from (
select input as input, 
       INSTR(input,'City=')+5 as citystart, 
       INSTR(input,'"', INSTR(input,'City=')) as cityend
from city) c;
```

Test data:

```
create table city (input char(64));

insert into city values('"City=Amsterdam"; "Customer=124"');

insert into city values('"Customer=11"; "City=USA"');

insert into city values('"Tel=+00"; "City=China"; "Customer=1"');

insert into city values('"Tel=+00"; "Post=11111";  "Customer=333"; "City=Canada"');
```

See updated [SQLFIDDLE:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1aed9/1)

Comment: I'm not sure that's exactly the same logic -- if the search string was 'ABC' against the string 'XCABCFVCG', for example?

Comment: David, I tried to read the question one more time. I understand it as the user4... wants to know the last index of '='. But maybe its not what he want?

Comment: This makes it totally different! You will need to find the citys start and end position. The start is easy (which is City=) and the end is???

Comment: as showed above, the City & Value is always in two "...", so I would mark the first " after City= as the end position.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you actually use:

```
INSTR(Input,'City=')+ length('City=') - 1
```

This seems to be the optimal code.